# What is the name of this song playing in My Hero Academia Season 2 Episode 9?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the name of the song playing in *My Hero Academia* Season 2 Episode 9 at around the 16min-17min mark?

Answer (score 0):

The track name is **Chokushi Dekinai Urara kasa**, if you have the OST collection it'll be in **Disk 1, Track 21**

[Here's the song on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61A19gSMMfc)